# Two questions about Independence of two RVs (building understanding)

Tags: probability

Situation A:

You are a math teacher writing a word problem for a quiz. You start off by stating,

- $X \sim Uniform(0,1)$
- $Y \sim Uniform(1,2)$
- $X$ and $Y$ are dependent

**My first question:** Does the last bullet point above make any sense? I don't think so... if I was writing a quiz question I couldn't use all the above bullet points at the same time. My thinking is the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are fully known and independent of eachother. Therefore $X$ and $Y$ can never be dependent.

---

Situation B:

- $X \sim Uniform(0,1)$
- $Y = X+1$
- Clearly $X$ and $Y$ are dependent since $X$ and $X+1$ are dependent.

**My second question:** What If I say, since $Y=X+1$ which means I fully know the unconditional distribution of $Y$ and that is $Y \sim Uniform(1,2)$, and therefore $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I know this isn't fair to say, because give you know $X$ that means you know $Y$, but what is wrong with the "fully know the distribution" argument above?

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: To sum up, of  course X uniform on (0,1) and Y uniform on (1,2) can be dependent, as the case Y=X+1 shows.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your help! How about this: the pdf of $Y \sim Uniform(0,1)$ can be expressed as $f_Y(y) =1$ which does not depend on $x$, and therefore $X$ and $Y=X+1$ are independent. I know this doesn't make sense... I suppose it depends on factoring apart $f_{X,X+1}(a,b)$ ...

Comment: Indeed this does not make sense. My advice: reread the definition of independence of random variables.

Comment: @Did I don't want to get on your bad side by seeming lazy as you have helped me many times on this site! Can you help put me in the right direction? Two continuous RVs are independent if you can factor the joint pdf into two marginal pdfs. In the case of $X$ and $X+1$ these are two RVs correct? Or is it one RV? If it's two, then it's a matter of showing $f_{X,X+1}(a,b) = f_X(a)f_{X+1}(b)$ is that right?

Comment: @Did also instead of talking through comments I am more than happy to upvote answers, if you have the time <3

Comment: Note that, as you write yourself, X and X+1 are **not** independent hence the factorization you are looking for does not exist. (Additionally, (X,X+1) has no joint PDF at all, but this is another story.)

Comment: @Did Ugh sorry I'm slow... so in Situation A of my original post, the example where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent via $Y=X+1$ doesn't actually work. Because in Situation A I imply that there does exist two separate RVs that do have a joint pdf. Also, I think your comment that $X,X+1$ wouldn't have a joint pdf makes sense to me if $X$ is one RV and not two two RVs with very similar distributions... (thank you)^1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment:** There are infinitely many joint distributions on
the rectangle with vertices at $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$
that have your specified uniform marginal distributions, and yet
are not independent.

An important principle here is that it is impossible, in general, to find the joint distribution corresponding to two marginal distributions (without additional information). However, if you know the two
marginal distributions are independent, then
the joint distribution can be found by multiplication.

In the upper half of the plot below (based on a simulation for
convenience in plotting), I illustrate an example where independence fails. Your example with
$X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ and $Y = X+1$ has what is sometimes called a
'degenerate joint distribution' with all probability
on a line. It is illustrated at the bottom of the figure.

In both cases, $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent because
$P(X < 1/2) = P(Y < 3/2) = 1/2,$ but
$P(X < 1/2,\,Y < 3/2) = 1/2 \ne 1/4.$

[image]

*Note:* The R code for making the figure is shown below
in case anyone is interested.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3));  m = 50000

 x = runif(m, 0, 1);  v = runif(m, 1 ,1.5)
 y = v;  y[x>1/2] = v[x>1/2]+ .5
   plot(x,y, pch=".")
   hist(x, br=10, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
   hist(y, br=10, prob=T, col="skyblue2")

 x = runif(m, 0, 1);  y = x+1
   plot(x,y, pch=".")
   hist(x, br=10, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
   hist(y, br=10, prob=T, col="skyblue2")

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: thank you for your insights Bruce. You bring up a key thing for me to remember, if you know the marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$ then the joint pdf doesn't necessarily follow if they are not independent. Thanks also for the R code. I will meditate on your answer.